# Having trouble with my 'if-else' statement, I dont know how to convert my textfields into integers (or something)

Tags: java, netbeans

I dont know how to convert my textfields (txtGood and txtBad) into integers so I tried string, didn't work. What should I use?

Tried 'String' as you can see:

```
private void btnSubstituteActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
    // TODO add your handling code here:

    String o, p;
    o = txtGood.getText();
    p = txtBad.getText();

    if(o = p) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "SampleQuoteGood", "Inspirational quote of the day:", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    }
```

I ran the program and my button (btnSubstitute) didn't work. Removing the 'if' and 'String' in the code works. It shows the JOptionpane and whatnot.

Comment: When checking for equality, you have 2 options: the `==` operator or the `.Equals()` method. In this case, since dealing with strings, this: ` if(o = p)` needs to become: `if (o.Equals(p))`.

Answer (score 1):

You *parse* the `String`. Like `int one = Integer.parseInt("1");` and comparison is `==` using `=` is assignment. So, something like

```
if (Integer.parseInt(o) == Integer.parseInt(p)) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `int o = Integer.valueOf(String s)`.

Use `==` instead of `=` in the `if` statement.